# Dapper query with DateTime

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm trying to use `Dapper` to query a table from my `ODBC` driver. The specific query I'm trying to run needs to return rows that have a `DateTime` value greater than the passed parameter to the query.

This is what I have tried:

```cs
string delta = "05/02/2019 08:41:37";
DateTime deltaDt = DateTime.Parse(delta);

using (IDbConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(/**Connection string**/))
{
    connection.Open();

    try
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Date > @Delta";
        IEnumerable<object> records = connection.Query<object>(query, new { Delta = deltaDt });

        Console.WriteLine(records.Count());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

However, with the above I get the following error:

```
{"ERROR [22018] Cannot convert non-numeric data"}
```

I then tried using `IDBConnection` without `Dapper` to see if I was just doing something incorrect, however the query works fine if I just do the following:

```cs
string delta = "05/02/2019 08:41:37";
DateTime deltaDt = DateTime.Parse(delta);

using (IDbConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(/**Connection string**/))
{
    connection.Open();

    string odbcQuery = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Date > ?";

    IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

    IDbDataParameter parameter = command.CreateParameter();
    parameter.Value = deltaDt;
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

    command.CommandText = odbcQuery;
    System.Data.IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        object[] values = new object[1];
        reader.GetValues(values);
        console.log(values);
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong when binding the `DateTime` using the `Dapper` query? As far as I can see the value is the same whether I use `Dapper` query or `IDbDataParameter`. I have also tried the following, but still get the same issue:

```cs
string query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Date > @Delta";
DynamicParameters dp = new DynamicParameters();
dp.Add("@Delta", deltaDt, DbType.DateTime);
IEnumerable<object> records = connection.Query<object>(query, dp);
```

Comment: What is the data type of the `MyTable.Date` column? Is it actually a date?

Comment: @mjwills That did help thanks. However I still don't understand why '@Delta' does not work but ?Delta? does.

Comment: @DavidG The underlying type is SQL_TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Date > ?Delta?
```

then

```
 IEnumerable<object> records = connection.Query<object>(query, new { Delta = deltaDt });
```

Comment: That does indeed work. Thank you. Can you please explain why this works whereas @Delta does not? Thanks.

Comment: @Kakalokia (hi, Dapper author here) - basically, the problem here is that your ODBC provider doesn't support named parameters, so `@Delta` *means nothing* to your database engine - it wants positional parameters; for convenience, dapper provides "pseudo-positional parameters" (naming is hard) - if you use `?Delta?`, dapper replaces it with the correct positional token, while also knowing which value to use for the parameter value (i.e. `args.Delta`)

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for the explanation Marc, appreciate it. It makes sense now.